# How to initialize a vector in a struct in c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am having a problem with vectors in c++. I am new to c++ so keep this in mind please.

So I have the following struct in the begining of my program:

```
typedef struct grupo
{
    float transX, transY, transZ, rotX, rotY, rotZ, rotAngle, scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ;
    char **modelos;
    struct grupo** grupos;
    int nNomes = 0, nGrupos=0;
    std::vector<float> vertices;
};

struct grupo *grupo;
```

And I just start the main like this:

```
grupo = (struct grupo*)malloc(sizeof(struct grupo));
grupo->modelos = (char **)malloc(sizeof(1));
grupo->grupos = (struct grupo **)malloc(sizeof(struct grupo));
```

And in the middle of main I am tryting to use this:

```
grupo->vertices.push_back(x);
```

But it keeps crashing the program. I am using visual studio, and using debugging mode. I can see that is when pushing X to the vector that crashes (x has a value). I've tried to change the vector to an array of floats. So the problem i can imagine is with the initialization of the vector... Can you help with what am I missing?

Thank you :)

Comment: This question is not about [c], so please do not tag it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are right, sorry about that.

Comment: I find it very confusing that your variable has the same name as the struct.

Comment: Also, try to get rid of the pointers and `malloc()` completely. Try to do it all with `std::vector` or other stl containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using C++; if you want to create a `grupo` dynamically, you should use the `new` operator, with the constructor:

```
grupo = new grupo();
```

`malloc` does not properly initialize C++ objects such as `std::vector`.

---

P.S. I am not sure what the `grupo->modelos` and `grupo->grupos` are supposed to be, but I'd use proper C++ types for them (perhaps `modelos` should be `std::string`, etc). Additionally, I suspect that you've got one `*` too much for both `modelos` and `grupos`.

Comment: This works :D Just wondering, does this make all the floats and ints on my struct default value of 0? Or should i force it in the struct to make them?

Comment: You should read about constructors and that you should not use pointers when you don't need it. No there is no default value for pods (int, chars..) unless you specify it.

Answer (score 6):

You're using C++, you don't need the "new" or malloc keyword unless for specific reasons. You don't need the typedef for structs.

I'm not sure what your char** is supposed to be, but you can use std::string for strings.

Maybe what you're trying to do is this:

```
struct Grupo
{
    float transX, transY, transZ, rotX, rotY, rotZ, rotAngle, scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ;
    std::string modelos;
    int nNomes = 0, nGrupos=0;
    std::vector<float> vertices;
};
```

In main:

```
Grupo grupo;
grupo.vertices.push_back( ... );
```

Then I would advise you to read a bit more about what is exactly the C++ language and how it's not C.

Comment: char** ? - I seldom use it.   With one exception.  "int main(int argv, char* argv[]);", can can be written as  "int main(int argv, char** argv);"

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not need the typedef in the declaration.

To properly initialize a structure, you should write a ctor to replace the compiler provided ctor (which generally does nothing).

Something like the following (with just a few attributes):

```
struct grupo
{
   float transX, transY;
   // ...
   int nNomes;
   int nGrupos;
   std::vector<float> vertices;

   // I prefer initialization list form
   grupo() : transX(0.0),
             transY(1.0),
             // ...
             nNomes(0),
             nGrupos(0)
             // vertices default ctor is ok, creates empty vector
      {
         // use vertices.push_back(...); to fill vertices
      }

};

grupo grupo;
```

Next you will want to write a more useful ctor, one with parameters to use (instead of the literal constants), such that you could build multiple grupo.

```
grupo grupo1(1.0, 2.0, 3, 4);
grupo grupo2(3.0, 4.0, 5, 6);
// etc.
```